# Creating a BreadCrumb Trail in FLex 4

Tags: flex4, breadcrumbs

Anyone has an idea how to do BreadCrumb Trails in Flex 4?

For example something like:

Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen 3

Is it possible after all?

Help Pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally navigate using currentState and ViewStacks.

Where ever you are just add link buttons on the screens separated by ">" and have their behaviour be the relevant state or stack change.

You could even dynamically add and remove buttons on entering the state.

It just depends how fancy you want to be.

But basically what you are asking is:

How do I make a button that goes to some place in my ui. Repeat for as many as needed.

click="currentState='TheNameOfTheState'"
click="SomeViewStackName.selectedIndex=1"

Thats all there is to it.